# Sorting an array list of words based on frequency and finding its frequency rank

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, ranking

I'm given a text file to read through. I can find the words in the text and file and their frequencies. I store this data in an `ArrayList<HashEntry>` where `HashEntry` consists of a key with the word and a value with the frequency. I sorted this `ArrayList` in decreasing frequency order using `Collections.sort`.

So I end up with something like this:

```
"a" 3, "a" 3, "a" 3, "now" 2, "days" 2, "everbody" 2, "wanna" 2, "they" 2,   
"they" 2, "their" 2, "just" 2, "now" 2, "days" 2, "talk" 1
```

I need to be able to produce something that will tell me the rank of occurrences. For example, "a" would have rank 1 because it appears the most. Everything that appears twice would have rank 2. "talk" would have rank 9 because there were 8 words that had a higher rank.

How would I go about doing this? I'm having several problems with what I've tried so far because there are duplicates in the `ArrayList` and the duplicates aren't necessarily sequential. I tried putting the data into a hash table by iterating through the `ArrayList`, where the key is the word, but I'm not sure how I could actually calculate the rank for the word.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ranked.size(); i++) { //ranked is my array list
            rankedht.put(ranked.get(i).getKey(),1); //rankedht is a hash table
        }
```

Doing that will just get me a hash table with the words and frequencies, but then that loses sort.

Thanks

Comment: Post what you have tried to get advices , answers or corrections.

Comment: Why are you storing duplicates? It sounds like you should just get rid of them. Unless I am misunderstand the requirements.

Comment: I'm not purposely storing duplicates. It's just the way I parse the text file creates duplicates and I'm not really sure how to get rid of them.

Comment: Put everything into a `Set`. It is a "collection that contains no duplicates." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: TreeMap would be best data stucture all you need to do is use the word as key and the occurences as value(your rank).

Comment: @aksam but the OP needs to sort the data

Comment: @aksam Not sure... isn't it the other way around? TreeMap sorts by the key, but he wants fast access by the word, so both the word and the occurrences have to be the key... Maybe just use a hashmap word -> occurrences for counting and use it for comparing the words when sorting.

Comment: Why are you using HashEntry? Why not a Map for the frequencies (which will take care of your duplicate problem) and a `List<Map.Entry>` to manipulate the order? Can you use java 8?

Comment: @tobias_k hashmap solution is great for faster lookup but the keys are not sorted is case of an hashmap so explict sorting is required.Regarding the performance of treemap they are built on top of rb-tree so insertion,deletion and lookup is going to take O(logn) time although if no insertion or deletion is to be performed the hashmap solution is good.